# Rewrite rule - strange behaviour with $_GET

Tags: php, get, url-rewriting

I have this rewire rule: ***EDITED***

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]// the problem is caused by this. How can I keep it without having this result?
RewriteRule    ^user/(.*)$    user.php?user=$1    [NC]    
RewriteRule ^ride/(.+)/$ ride.php?myRideId=$1 [NC,L]
```

when I do this:

```
www.example.com/ride/123
```

everything works fine and my browser correctly shows the above page but if I try to use:

```
  $rideId = $_GET['myRideId'];
  echo $rideId;
```

the result is:

```
123.php/123
```

I don't understand why. Anything wrong in the rewrite rule?

Comment: what does print_r($_GET); give you in results?

Comment: @MihirChhatre Array ( [myRideId] => 123.php/123 )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this?

```
RewriteRule ^ride/(.+)/?$ ride.php?myRideId=$1 [NC,L]
```

Try this. Also you will need to write your URL as:

```
www.example.com/ride/123/
```

Comment: if i do this: www.example/ride/123/ I get 123/.php/123/ otherwise I still get the above results with  www.example/ride/123 (also with the new rule)

Comment: How about :
    RewriteRule ^ride/(.+)/$ ride.php?myRideId=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: SORRY, I should have posted all the rewrite rules. That would have helped to find the solution. The problem was RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]
which is before all the other rules. I will edit my question. is there a way to keep that rule without having that result?

Comment: try writing the code about the line where you have written :<br/><br/>
RewriteRule ^ride/(.+)$ ride.php?myRideId=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user.php?user=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC] <br/><br/>

Comment: I get "500 internal server error". it only works if I remove RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC] but I would like to keep it because it change all my other pages from www.example.com/foo.php to just www.example.com/foo

Comment: okay - don't remove that line. 

Did you write the above code as i supplied it? as in, in the same order? you want to have the ride & user URL's re-write first and then move to the rewriting of all the other url's.

Comment: I copied and pasted  it exactly as you wrote it.